# Find the joint distribution for variables in an experiment

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a container contains 5 articles, there are 2 defective. Suppose that the articles are tested one after the other until identifying the 2 defective articles.

If $X$ represents be the number of tests needed to identify the first defective article, and $Y$ is the number of additional tests needed to identify the other one. Describe by a table the joint probability distribution for $(X, Y)$, then Calculate $E(X)$.

I tried as:

Generally, calculate $p(X=i,Y=j), j >i$ because as it is written in the question $Y$ is the additional tests done so I need to keep testing after finding the first one.

Hence, I have

\begin{align} \forall j \leq i,~&p(X=i,Y=j) = 0  & i,j &\in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \\
&p(X=1,Y=j) = \text{?} & j &\in \{ 2, 3, 4, 5\} \\
&p(X=2,Y=j) = \text{?} &  j &\in \{ 3, 4, 5\} \\
&p(X=3,Y=j) = \text{?} &  j &\in \{ 4, 5\} \\
&p(X=4,Y=5) = \text{?} 
\end{align}

To calculate, for example, $p(X=1,Y=2)$. I have defective then defective so the probability the first is defective is $\frac{2}{5}$ and the probability the second is defective given that the first is defective = $\frac{1}{4}$. Thus $p(X=1,Y=2)=\frac{1}{10}$. and to continue as this to calculate the the joint distribution.

Is this correct? Also, I don't know how to fine the expectation for X. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Y$ is the number of **additional** tests to be taken, so that - if e.g. $X=2$ - it is quite well possible that $Y$ takes value $1$ or $2$.

Here $X,Y$ are positive integers that satisfy $X+Y\leq5$.

So $(X,Y)$ takes values in: $$A:=\{(i,j)\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\mid i+j\leq5\}$$

Observe that $A$ contains $\binom52=10$ elements and that these elements all have equal chance to become the value of $(X,Y)$.

This implies that $$P(X=i,Y=j)=\frac1{10}$$ for every $(i,j)\in A$.

Now you can find $P(X=i)=\sum_{j=1}^{5-i}P(X=i,Y=j)$ for every $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ enabling you to find: $$\mathbb EX=\sum_{i=1}^5iP(X=i)$$